# Does RewriteRule on htaccess file affect FTP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, ftp

I have redirected my domain with a RewriteRule on the htaccess file on another domain's index page. Does this method affect the FTP connection?

If yes how can I bypass that?

Comment: That's a bit of a broad question? What is your actual issue? FTP does not go through .htaccess. Web server uses HTTP protocol. FTP is a different protocol used for a different purpose. Not sure why you think it's an .htaccess issue whatever the problem is.

Comment: The issue is that I have been using the redirection like that a month now and now the "host" of the website is telling me that this causes the problem. But the thing is that I remember connecting to the FTP AFTER the redirection. So I wanted to make sure if thats the case.

Comment: The error that I am getting when I try to access the page is "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED"

Comment: `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED` that says DNS error. Check DNS and the URL you're accessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.htaccess` is Apache web server configuration file. The Apache is HTTP server. It has nothing to do with FTP.

So the `.htaccess` does not affect the FTP.

---

Even if it had impact, the FTP protocol does not support a redirection anyway.

See [Can I send HTTP headers on an FTP URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28584982/850848)