# Redirecting FTP to http in IIS

Tags: http, redirect, iis, ftp

I have an FTP server published using IIS of windows server 2012.
I have created a new website which I would like users to use instead of the FTP server.
Users only know my FTP server.
Is there a way to redirect FTP requests to http requests of my new website ?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: But it's not doable anyway, see [Can I send HTTP headers on an FTP URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28584982/850848).

Comment: Technically impossible. FTP won’t redirect to HTTP.